# SMS Registration Error with Twilio

Tags: twilio, botframework

The Microsoft bot framework is returning the error "Provided phone number does not belong to Twilio account." when I try to connect it to my Twilio phone number.  It works with Skype, Slack and Facebook but this SMS connector will not let me get past the registration.  What gives?  is there a known issue with this part?

Comment: Hi Chuck, can you check that the Account SID and Token are correct?

Comment: ...of course.  That is not the error I am getting

Comment: Okay, I ask only because the API will return that error in that instance which is not as specific as it could be. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21606. But I realize now, this is an error you are receiving via this particular framework only?

Comment: Yes.  I even changed my Account SID on purpose to an invalid one and then I get the Account Could not be verified.  So, I think the Account SID and Token are not the problem.  I have tried everything and cannot get it to take my phone number.

Comment: Come on!  Someone out there knows the what the problem is with my account?  Help Please.

Comment: The Facebook messenger connector does not work either.  Gives me BADREQUEST when I click the Register button.  All of my information is correct but just DOES NOT WORK!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, I had failed to put the "+" in front of the phone number. It worked fine once this was in place.

eg.
+44753....
rather than
44753....

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...I will write my own SMS connector.  Easier they using yours anyway

Comment: I added the + and left off the +.  Does not work.  Phone numbers here in the USA start with a 1 so something like +14045901234 is what I am using.